# Nav Menu - Drop down menu z-index?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, nav

been working on a site building software and have a bug thats driving me nuts:

when you go to

http://dalarandaily.com/home-and-auto

And you mouse over the nav the drop downs go behind the content.

I cant figure it out. Ive tried just about everything I know of and others
that I found on research and nothing seems to be working right.

I just need to make sure the nav menu displays over the top of the content
and not under it like its doing.

If anyone could take a look at the css and maybe offer up a suggestion
it would be greatly appreciated. The css can be seen here
http://dalarandaily.com/main.css

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rule for `ul.nav`, position it relative and change z-index from -1000 to positive 1000.  This worked from the inspector tools for `ul.nav`:

```
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Worked perfectly! Thanks SOOoo much!